# How to delete a folder with fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I have a folder in my repository.I want to delete that folder after tests.I can delete files as below but ,how can I delete a folder like below code ?

`await fs.promises.rm('./fixtures/asset');`

Above code deletes asset file but I want to delete all fixtures folder?Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
await fs.promises.rm('./fixtures', { recursive: true, force: true });
```

or

```
fs.rmdirSync("./fixtures", { recursive: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`rmdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesrmdirpath-options) to the complete folder like that :

```js
await fs.promises.rmdir('./fixtures');
```

You can add `{ recursive: true }` for subfolders, like that:

```js
await fs.promises.rmdir('./fixtures', { recursive: true });
```